# Why do teeth decay of sugar?

Tags: human-biology, mammals

Sugars is a common component in diet of mammals. Why then their teeth did not develop resistence to sugar decay?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the decay are ever evolving bacteria, which happen to be very hard to overcome, even nowdays. There is a lot of research centered towards protein interactions, even mapping whole interactomes, which would help us get rid of decay, yet naturally our system wasn't able to evolve as fast as technological advances, but bacteria did.